# How to find if two arrays contain any common item in sql

Tags: sql, mysql++

I'm trying to filter my tables using WHERE to check whether 2 arrays share any common items using SQL but having difficulties coming up with syntax, do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your database tables, sample data, current output, and expected out.

Answer (score 0):

You are about using 'join' structure

Giving that you using same id on 2 tables 'customer' and 'product' then the sql should be :

```
Select * from customer c inner join product p 
on c.id = p.id
```